# Strict linter but loose compiler

Tags: angular, typescript

I know I can set **compiler** option in tsconfig.json. But I want to set different options for the **linter**. Angular dropped the tslint.json file so I can't set compiler options there.

Basically I want the linter to nag me hard about bad practices but let me go ahead and compile.

How do I keep the compiler options loose so I can compile but the linter options strict?

Comment: Sure @Anand. I'm RapPayne on all socials including github and linkedIn.

Comment: It would be incredibly foolish for anyone to put their phone number in a public forum like this. So, no. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the linter you can use with your updated Angular projects:
https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint

Here's an example of configuring it:

https://youtu.be/IDBdtQlugtw